# Deserialize XML by walking into the tree: There was an error reflecting type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have this XML as a result of an API. Using DotNetXmlDeserializer as deserializer.

```
<results>
   <result inum=\"802469000014312\">
      <field name=\"startedat\">2019-09-04T15:59:56.372</field>
      <field name=\"duration\">8</field>
      <field name=\"otherparties\">1043 (DEMO BLA BLA), 0519331839</field>
      <field name=\"switchcallid\">00001000081567605580</field>
      <field name=\"udfs\"></field>
   </result>
   <result inum=\"802469000014313\">
      <field name=\"startedat\">2019-09-04T16:00:31.414</field>
      <field name=\"duration\">6</field>
      <field name=\"otherparties\">1043 (DEMO BLA BLA), 0519331839</field>
      <field name=\"switchcallid\">00001000091567605608</field>
      <field name=\"udfs\"></field>
   </result>
```

I'm using this classes for deserialization

```
[XmlRoot("results")]
public class WFOQueryDTO_List
{
    public WFOQueryDTO_List() { Items = new List<WFOQueryDTO_Out>(); }
    [XmlElement("result")]
    public List<WFOQueryDTO_Out> Items { get; set; }
}

public class WFOQueryDTO_Out
{
    [XmlElement("field")]
    [XmlAttribute("startedat")]
    public DateTime startedat { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("field")]
    [XmlElement("duration")]
    public int duration { get; set; }


    [XmlElement("field")]
    [XmlElement("otherparties")]
    public string otherparties { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("field")]
    [XmlElement("switchcallid")]
    public string switchcallid { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("field")]
    [XmlElement("udfs")]
    public string udfs { get; set; }

}
```

But I get:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type ...For non-array types, you may use the following attributes: XmlAttribute, XmlText, XmlElement, or XmlAnyElement.
```

Comment: You need a private and public property for the field elements.  So you need a get/set interface.  Simpl.  Will post answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, that shape isn't directly supported by `XmlSerializer`. You will need to do this in two steps:

1. deserialize with a list of raw fields
2. map from your raw fields to the actual fields to WFOQueryDTO_Out by recognizing each field name manually, applying whatever per-type parse logic you need for each named field

By "list of raw fields", I mean:

```
[XmlElement("field")]
public List<Field> Fields {get;} = new List<Field>();

public class Field {
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [XmlText]
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

---

To do this *properly* (and easily), you'd need input xml of the more typical strongly-defined form:

```xml
<startedat>2019-09-04T15:59:56.372</startedat>
<duration>8</duration>
<otherparties>1043 (DEMO BLA BLA), 0519331839</otherparties>
<switchcallid>00001000081567605580</switchcallid>
<udfs></udfs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication128
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<root>" +
                   "<results>" +
                      "<result inum=\"802469000014312\">" +
                         "<field name=\"startedat\">2019-09-04T15:59:56.372</field>" +
                         "<field name=\"duration\">8</field>" +
                         "<field name=\"otherparties\">1043 (DEMO BLA BLA), 0519331839</field>" +
                         "<field name=\"switchcallid\">00001000081567605580</field>" +
                         "<field name=\"udfs\"></field>" +
                      "</result>" +
                      "<result inum=\"802469000014313\">" +
                         "<field name=\"startedat\">2019-09-04T16:00:31.414</field>" +
                         "<field name=\"duration\">6</field>" +
                         "<field name=\"otherparties\">1043 (DEMO BLA BLA), 0519331839</field>" +
                         "<field name=\"switchcallid\">00001000091567605608</field>" +
                         "<field name=\"udfs\"></field>" +
                      "</result>" +
                   "</results>" +
                "</root>";
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            Root root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlArray("results")]
        [XmlArrayItem("result")]
        public WFOQueryDTO_Out[] WFOQueryDTO_Out { get; set; } 
    }
    public class WFOQueryDTO_Out
    {
        private DateTime startedat { get; set; }
        private int duration { get; set; }
        private string otherparties { get; set; }
        private string switchcallid { get; set; }
        private string udfs { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("field")]
        public Field[] field
        {
            get { return new Field[1]; }
            set
            {
                foreach(Field _field in value)
                {
                    switch (_field.name)
                    {
                        case "startedat":
                            startedat = DateTime.Parse(_field.value);
                            break;
                        case "duration":
                            duration = int.Parse(_field.value);
                            break;
                        case "otherparties" :
                            otherparties = _field.value;
                            break;
                        case "switchcallid" :
                            switchcallid = _field.value;
                            break;
                        case " udfs" :
                            udfs = _field.value;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public class Field
    {

        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You for the efforts. This solution looks good. Anyway it doesn't add something more to the first answered.

Comment: The other solution  returns all strings.  My solution get date, integer, and string.